# Go signal handling

Tags: go, signals

I'm quite new to Go and in a quite a rut trying to figure out how to handle events that need to return back to the main loop.

In C, I can just return the function back but it seems I can't do that here, at least with that method.

I can handle signals that need to be processed within sigHandler() i.e. SIGINT or SIGTERM but I need to return calls back to main when handling SIGHUP or SIGUSR. In my code below, the process just stuck in wait mode once I sent the hangup signal.

I appreciate if someone can help me to guide on how I can properly design the signal handling to handle calls that need to return to main code which is in the first goroutine.

### Edit

I'm now handling channel messages in the main goroutine within select{} but the code below quits when I'm sending the HUP signal. The objective here is to reload the config and continue execution as normal.

In the main line code, I have this:

```
go sigHandler()
cs := make(chan bool, 1)
go sigHandler(cs)

// setup the http server
err := setupServer(addr, port)
if err != nil {
    fatal("Error setting up listening sockets")
    os.Exit(1)
}

    select {
    case quit := <-cs:
        if quit {
            logEvent(loginfo, sys, "Terminating..")
            closeLog()
            os.Exit(0)
        } else {
            logEvent(loginfo, sys, "Reloading configuration..")
            }
    }
```

The function sigHandler()

```
func sigHandler(cs chan bool) {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGHUP)

    signal := <-c
    logEvent(lognotice, sys, "Signal received: "+signal.String())

    switch signal {
    case syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM:
        cs <- true
    case syscall.SIGHUP:
            cs <- false
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on `SIGHUP`?  Most Go programs don't really have the concept of a main loop, but you could easily pass a notification between goroutines via another channel.

Comment: You should get familiar with channels, IMHO. They do what you’re looking for.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I've added a channel between the main and signal handling but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

// We make sigHandler receive a channel on which we will report the value of var quit
func sigHandler(q chan bool) {
    var quit bool

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGHUP)

    // foreach signal received
    for signal := range c {
        // logEvent(lognotice, sys, "Signal received: "+signal.String())

        switch signal {
        case syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM:
            quit = true
        case syscall.SIGHUP:
            quit = false
        }

        if quit {
            quit = false
            // closeDb()
            // logEvent(loginfo, sys, "Terminating..")
            // closeLog()
            os.Exit(0)
        }
        // report the value of quit via the channel
        q <- quit
    }
}

func main() {
    // init two channels, one for the signals, one for the main loop
    sig := make(chan bool)
    loop := make(chan error)

    // start the signal monitoring routine
    go sigHandler(sig)

    // while vat quit is false, we keep going
    for quit := false; !quit; {
        // we start the main loop code in a goroutine
        go func() {
            // Main loop code here
            // we can report the error via the chan (here, nil)
            loop <- nil
        }()

        // We block until either a signal is received or the main code finished
        select {
        // if signal, we affect quit and continue with the loop
        case quit = <-sig:
        // if no signal, we simply continue with the loop
        case <-loop:
        }
    }
}
```

However, note that the signal will cause the main loop to continue, but it will not stop the execution on the first goroutine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of structuring things to do what you want,
separating concerns so that the signal-handling code
and the main code are separate and easily tested independently.

How you implement Quit and ReloadConfig is entirely up
to your program - ReloadConfig may send a "please reload"
value on a channel to a running goroutine; it may lock
a mutex and change some shared configuration data; or some
other possibility.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    obj := &myObject{}
    go handleSignals(obj)
    select {}
}

type myObject struct {
}

func (obj *myObject) Quit() {
    log.Printf("quitting")
    os.Exit(0)
}

func (obj *myObject) ReloadConfig() {
    log.Printf("reloading configuration")
}

type MainObject interface {
    ReloadConfig()
    Quit()
}

func handleSignals(main MainObject) {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGHUP)
    for sig := range c {
        switch sig {
        case syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM:
            main.Quit()
            return
        case syscall.SIGHUP:
            main.ReloadConfig()
        }
    }
}
```